# get the value of ArrayList of String value

Tags: java, arrays, jackson, java-stream, jackson-databind

Please I have List containing below value

```
[ { "sender" : "sys" , "message" : [ "Hello, " , "how are you?"] ,"transaction_date" : { "$date" : "2019-02-14T17:34:12.705Z"} , "has_suggestions" : true } , { "sender" : "user" , "message" : [ "Hello." , "hey you"] , "visited" : true , "transaction_status" : "Succeded" , "transaction_date" : { "$date" : "2019-02-14T17:34:12.705Z"} , "has_suggestions" : true , "suggestion_list" : [ "Yes, I am." , "No, I am not."] , "suggestion_list_type" : "buttons"}, { "sender" : "sys" , "message" : { "has_form" : true , "form_type" : "prehandover_form" , "data" : { "text" : [ "Kindly provide your info"]}} , "visited" : false , "transaction_status" : "Succeded" , "transaction_date" : { "$date" : "2019-02-14T17:34:15.386Z"}}]
```

I tried to traverse through the content of the JSON data using Jackson JsonNode below the the code:

```
ObjectMapper object = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = object.readTree(value);
String sender = jsonNode.get("sender").textValue();
```

But am getting a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Please any help to traverse through the the JSON data will highly be appreciated.

Comment: You have a json array, read `jsonNode.get(0).get("sender")`

Comment: You receive an array not an object

Comment: after doing `JsonNode jsonNode = object.readTree(value);`, `jsonNode` will contain an array. `jsonNode.get("sender")` will return null. Which element(s) of the array are you interested in?

Comment: your JSON has mixture of `Key: value` and `Key: Array`

Comment: @vizsatiz, thanks that approach works.

Comment: @Maurice Perry, yes its return a null value, i am interested in get any of the elements

Comment: @AfeezOlawale then I would get the first one, as in vizsatiz' comment

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the ArrayList from JsonNode.
Here is your solution.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
String sender = jsonNode.get(0).get("sender").textValue();
```

Comment: thanks @Nitin I had to loop through the Jsonnode for each value since the my JsonNode is an array. I appreciate!

Comment: Welcome @AfeezOlawale. It would be more appreciated if you up-vote the answer. Thanks In advance.

Comment: well solution didnt answer the question do, but lead to me to the resoutions.

Answer (score 0):

JsonNode contains multiple objects. Due to read all sender elements, you may use following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("src\\main\\java\\json.txt");
        FileInputStream value = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectMapper object = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = object.readTree(value);
        for (int i=0;i<jsonNode.size();i++){
            System.out.println(jsonNode.get(i).findValue("sender").textValue());
        }
    }
```